# Median of areas given in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, data-structures

Given a matrix (n x n) of 1 and 0, where 1 represent land and 0 represent water. 
How can I find the median of the area of the lands in the most efficient way?

For Example:

1 1 0 0 0

1 0 0 1 1

1 0 1 0 0

There are three islands, the area of them [1,2,4] and the median is 2

**An island can be consist of continuous non-diagonal cells which contain 1:**
For example:

1  0 1

0  1 0

this matrix contains three islands of areas [1,1,1]

My solution is finding recursively the areas and then sort them to find the median which takes O(n^2log(n^2)), is there a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: Do you want just the median value, or do you want to identify an island that has the median?  Also, it would help if you clarify what you mean by "island".

Comment: I have edited it the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step, run DFS recursively on the grid and discover all the islands & calculate areas in `O(n^2)` time.

Second step, You can use [Median of Medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) algorithm to calculate the median of unsorted island's areas array in expected `O(m)` time where `m` is the number of islands.

Overall time complexity `O(n^2)`.

If you need further help, I can provide my implementation.

Comment: [`O(m log m)` sorting is unnecessary](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/find-median-of-unsorted-array-in-on-time).

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thanks for pointing out. Can you please check the update?

Comment: Median of medians is an approximate estimate, not an exact one.

Comment: @pjs yes, you're right. That's why I mentioned its **expected** `O(n)` time.

Comment: The expected time to get a potentially wrong answer is not relevant.

Comment: @pjs, are you sure? I think it is exactly `O(n)`

Comment: @BagdanGilevich The time calculation is correct, but the result is an approximation of the median, not guaranteed to be the median.  This is stated in the very first sentence of the linked Wikipedia article.  OP stated they wish to "find" the median, implying the goal is an exact solution.

Comment: @pjs Wikipedia is wrong here. The median of medians algorithm isn't literally to return the median of medians, rather, the algorithm is to use that element as the pivot for QuickSelect, giving an exact answer in linear time by Case 3 of the Master Theorem.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Then I'd like to see the answer state that explicitly.  As is, it says that the median of medians will be used to calculate the answer in O(m) time, hence my statement that it's only an approximate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [disjoint set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) gives you O(A(N)), where A is inverse Ackermann function to find the Islands, then using an nth_element (aka [IntroSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect)) to find the N/2 in O(N) to find the median.

```
sets = DisjointSet(matrix)
median = nth_element(sets, N/2)
```

For a total of O(A(N)) far less than O(N^2)